# Delete XML nodes if subnode contains particular string

Tags: xml, bash, shell

Need to delete some nodes from the XML file if a subnode contains the particular string or word, Sample XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/3982474/sitemap_nb.xsl"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">


  <url>
       <loc>https://www.test.com/home</loc>
       <lastmod>2020-08-03T14:41:44+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>0.8000</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
       <loc>https://www.test.com/features?xxxxx=serviceability-point-access</loc>
       <lastmod>2020-08-03T14:41:44+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>0.5120</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
       <loc>https://www.test.com/eu/index</loc>
       <lastmod>2020-08-03T14:41:44+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>0.8000</priority>
  </url>
<url>
       <loc>https://www.test.com/features?xxxxx=serviceability-point-access</loc>
       <lastmod>2020-08-03T14:41:44+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>0.5120</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
       <loc>https://www.test.com/models/s510/features?xxxxx=serviceability</loc>
       <lastmod>2020-08-03T14:41:44+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>0.5120</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
       <loc>https://www.test.com/index</loc>
       <lastmod>2020-08-03T14:41:44+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>0.8000</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

find the string "xxxxx" and delete the set of the node

Results should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/3982474/sitemap_nb.xsl"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">


  <url>
       <loc>https://www.test.com/home</loc>
       <lastmod>2020-08-03T14:41:44+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>0.8000</priority>
  </url>
  
  <url>
       <loc>https://www.test.com/eu/index</loc>
       <lastmod>2020-08-03T14:41:44+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>0.8000</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
       <loc>https://www.test.com/index</loc>
       <lastmod>2020-08-03T14:41:44+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>0.8000</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

I used the following sed comment but it's omitting the urlset's element attributes. I am not expert on  shell script, please check and suggest what I am missing.

```
sed -ne '/?xml/{ p; b }; /urlset/{ p; b }; /<url/{ h; b }; H; /<\/url>/{ x; /?xxxxx/b; /?xxxxx/b; p }'
```

The above sed produce below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/3982474/sitemap_nb.xsl"?>
<urlset
     
  <url>
       <loc>https://www.test.com/home</loc>
       <lastmod>2020-08-03T14:41:44+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>0.8000</priority>
  </url>
<url>
       <loc>https://www.test.com/eu/index</loc>
       <lastmod>2020-08-03T14:41:44+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>0.8000</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
       <loc>https://www.test.com/index</loc>
       <lastmod>2020-08-03T14:41:44+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>0.8000</priority>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

The urlset node and attributes is missing
can someone help me?... Thank you

Comment: You don't parse XML markup with `sed` as you don't drive-in a screw with a hammer. Use the right tools for the job. Use an XML parser and processor like xmlstarlet, xsltproc, saxon...

Comment: We are using CentOS 6.10, it's not allowing to install snapd to install xmlstarlet.So decided to use sed

Comment: @Rajaguru check if it is already installed, under the name `xml`.

Comment: @thanasisp I can only `xmllint , xmlcatalog, xmlwf` from my sever not 'xmlstarlt' and 'xml' . Could you please check and suggest.

Comment: They do not edit xml.

Comment: @thanasisp finally installed ```xmlstarlet``` and fixed the issue, solution updated. Thanks for help.

Comment: Very well, welcome!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The XML's root element  has the following namespace attributes, this causes the issue.

```
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
```

The `xmlstarlet-1.5.0+`suggested to use prefix '*' brefore node (For instance, use /*:node instead of /node). http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html

`xmlstarlet ed -d "//_:urlset/_:url[*[contains(text(),'xxxxx')]]" file.xml`

This solution works perfectly for the above problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `xmlstarlet` (for some shells by default named `xml` also)

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//urlset/url[loc[contains(text(), "xxxxx")]]' file.xml
```

This will delete all `<url>` nodes having a subnode `<loc>` containing the text `xxxxx`.

Comment: `sed -ne '/?xml/{ p; b }; /?xml-stylesheet/{ p; b }; /urlset/{ p; b }; /<url/{ h; b }; H; /<\/url>/{ x; /?xxxxx/b; /?xxxxx/b; p }'`   -- This sed comment remove nodes but at the same time it's remove <ruleset> nodes attributes too..anyone help is appericiated.

Comment: xmlstarlet install require snapd but CentOS 6.10 not allowing to install snapd . so we decided to use sed.